# Pulling a Database from Heroku and not able to process data

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, heroku

I used pg:pull to pull a database to my local database. It was all working as expected until it got to the processing data step.

Here is the error I received, it was on the first entry in the database.

```
pg_restore: processing data for table "a1pavingco.account_emailaddress"
pg_restore: error: unrecognized data block type (0) while searching archive
events.js:287
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: write EPIPE
   at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:154:25)
   at writeGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:145:3)
   at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:784:11)
   at Socket._write (net.js:796:8)
   at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:442:12)
   at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:426:5)
   at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:317:11)
   at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:695:22)
   at Socket.emit (events.js:310:20)
   at Socket.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:493:10)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
   at errorOrDestroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:108:12)
   at Socket.onerror (_stream_readable.js:729:7)
   at Socket.emit (events.js:310:20)
   at errorOrDestroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:108:12)
   at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:457:5)
   at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:484:5)
   at internal/streams/destroy.js:50:7
   at Socket._destroy (net.js:677:5)
   at Socket.destroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:38:8)
   at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:154:17) {
errno: 'EPIPE',
code: 'EPIPE',
syscall: 'write'
}
```

I don't know what to make of this error or how to fix it. I can see the database via PGAdmin however there are no entries within the columns. I have tested that with queries that returned nothing. Any advice on how to solve this problem will be much appreciated!